# setting position of a figure at current plot location in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to record sound from mic using pyaudio and plotting it at the same time (in parallel with recording).

I have created a horizontal plot window, who's size is bigger than the main application window.

Code section:

```
    self.fig, self.ax1 = plt.subplots()
    rect = self.fig.patch
    rect.set_facecolor('white')
    #self.ax1.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    self.ax1.set_autoscale_on(True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, top=0.95, right=10.0)
```

I am not able to move plot area to the current location of plotting or may be at the end of horizontal plot window. I also tried to use scrolled window. That also didn't work.

any idea?

Comment: if you are embedding matplotlib in something else do not import `pyplot`

Comment: and this answer will really depend on what tool kit you are using, which you have not told us

Comment: i am using pygtk with python2.7 on windows. how to embed matplotlib figure in pygtk-> scrolled window?

Comment: you should include those details in the question.

Comment: and show us what you are doing now.